# JIRA Issue Key Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to have a regex to match and pull out BUG-123 from this sentence:

```
some junk here BUG-123 My bug description goes here
```

Thanks

Comment: Which language are you using the regex with? Java? What is `xxx` and `yyy`? And what have you tried?

Comment: I'm going to use Regex with C#.  xxx and yyy are just junk text that may appear before the bug number in the commit message.

Comment: I need to parse any of the above snippets using regex and return the bug number(s).  I simplified the issue since it was confusing people.

Comment: You don't know RegExp's at all, do you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `BUG-(\d+)`

So it would be

```
List<string> bugNos=Regex.Matches(yourString,@"BUG-(\d+)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                       .Cast<Match>()
                       .Select(x=>x.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: This is 100% what I was looking for.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The RegExp is below. It will parse through all the lines.

```
(?m)BUG-([^ ]+)
```

Comment: I just wrote the following code in C#, which returns false: new Regex("/BUG-([^ ]+)/g").IsMatch("BUG-123").  I updated my original post to make this much simpler.

Comment: @AdamLevitt no this would work fine..you are not using the regex properly...remove `/` from the regex

Comment: @ualinker ur regex is correct..but this is `c#` not `php`..no need of `/`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the note! I know RegExps but I am not familiar with C#, unfortunately

Comment: there's no need for `m` either

Comment: The original post contained much more information at first. That bug IDs may be text and that it may be contained on multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

For a related StackOverflow question ([Regular expression for a JIRA identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322669/regular-expression-for-a-jira-identifier)) , I found a semi-official regex from Atlassian themselves (for Java), and I ported it to JavaScript.

Java version:

```regex
((?<!([A-Za-z]{1,10})-?)[A-Z]+-\d+)
```

JavaScript version (requires that everything be reversed first, though):

```js
var jira_matcher = /\d+-[A-Z]+(?!-?[a-zA-Z]{1,10})/g
```

More details here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30518972/290254

Answer (score 0):

I just looked into creating a regex for jira issues and found this entry.
I found some testdata to match

```
VALID:
JIRA-1 BIN-10000 A-1 TACO-7133 X-88 BF-18 ABC-1 BINGO-1 BUG-123
NOT VALID:
JIRA-01 BIN-10000000 abc-123 ABCDEFGHIJKL-999 abc XY-Z-333 abcDEF-33
VALID no \s Ending
JIRA-1
```

And came up with (research + original work) a .net regex that should match the valid ones and not match the invalid ones:

```
(?<!([^\s]))([A-Z]{1,10}-[1-9][0-9]{0,6})(?=(\s|$))
```

[permalink to playground](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%28%5b%5e%5cs%5d%29%29%28%5bA-Z%5d%7b1%2c10%7d-%5b1-9%5d%5b0-9%5d%7b0%2c6%7d%29%28%3f%3d%28%5cs%7c%24%29%29&i=VALID%3a%0d%0aJIRA-1+BIN-10000+A-1+TACO-7133+X-88+BF-18+ABC-1+BINGO-1+BUG-123%0d%0aNOT+VALID%3a%0d%0aJIRA-01+BIN-10000000+abc-123+ABCDEFGHIJKL-999+abc+XY-Z-333+abcDEF-33%0d%0aVALID+no+%5cs+Ending%0d%0aJIRA-1)

Sources worth mentioning:
[so-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322669/regular-expression-for-a-jira-identifier/30518972#30518972)
[atlassians regex](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/integrating-with-custom-jira-issue-key-313460921.html?_ga=2.19343932.522454812.1532963741-519237518.1520857350)
[atlassioan forum](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Regex-pattern-to-match-JIRA-issue-key/qaq-p/233319)