# How to check if a Github PR has a valid JIRA ticket in the Title from Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, jira

I have a scenario where I don't want to allow merging a Pull Request in Github if the title doesn't have a valid JIRA ticket number. I am using Jenkins for our CI/CD so wanted to do some checks using Jenkins itself. I am planning to fail a build in the CI if the build is triggered by merging a Pull Request and the title doesn't have a valid JIRA ticket number in it.

I am using GitHub organization job and did come across [github scm filter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-scm-filter-jira-validator/) plugin which claims to provide the PR title checks but after configuring, it doesn't work for me.

Is there a way where I can achieve the PR title checks using Jenkins? or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it manually. You first need to get the PR title when the build starts using either a Jenkins plugin that works with GitHub, or by using the [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest?apiVersion=2022-11-28). You can then use regex to extract possible Jira IDs ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30518972/3730626)).

You could then use a Jira plugin for Jenkins ([such as this one](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jira/)) or the [Jira Rest API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/) to search for the Jira ID. If the ID exists, then you're good to go. Otherwise, you could fail the build.